# Error con la validación para insertar valores en mi tabla

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-11g

Tengo que hacer que el atributo fechapedido sea igual a la del sistema, así que le coloque el valor del SYSDATE por default, además tengo que validar que la fecha debe ser superior al 01-01-2020; lo hice así, pero creo que tengo un error de sintaxis del que no me doy cuenta.

```
create table pedido(
                IdPedido number(12) not null,
                Empno number(10) not null,
                IdCli number(10) not null,
                fechapedido date DEFAULT SYSDATE not null, 
                fechaact date not null,
                Importe number(38) not null,
             CONSTRAINT PRIc_KEY PRIMARY KEY (IdPedido)
             );

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER pedido_TRIG3 BEFORE INSERT ON pedido for each row
begin
if:new.fechapedido <= TO_DATE('2020/01/01', 'YYYY/MM/DD') then
raise_application_error(-20001,'la fecha debe ser mayor a la del 01-01-2020');
elsif :new.fechaact <= :new.fechapedido then
raise_application_error(-20001,'la fecha de actualización debe ser mayor a la de fecha del pedido');
end if;
end;
/
```

> Al insertar valores manualmente me permite crear la fila, ejem:

```
insert into pedido values ('0128','123','1001',TO_DATE('2021/08/10', 'yyyy/mm/dd'),TO_DATE('2021/08/15', 'yyyy/mm/dd'), '25');
```

> Al insertar valores con el SYSDATE así:

```
insert into pedido values ('0129','124','1002',TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'yyyy/mm/dd'),TO_DATE('2019/08/15', 'yyyy/mm/dd'), '25');
```

> me arroja la sentencia de error que creé:
> ORA-20001: la fecha debe ser mayor a la del 01-01-2020

No se me ocurre que pueda ser.

Comment: `sysdate` ya es date, no tienes que convertirlo con `to_date()`, simplemente usa `sysdate`.

Answer (score 0):

El SYSDATE es una función que devuelve la fecha y hora del sistema operativo donde se encuentra la base de datos. Lo devuelve de tipo DATE, por lo tanto, no se deberia utilizar en una función de conversión de VARCHAR a DATE como lo estaba haciendo: `TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'yyyy/mm/dd')` porque  el resultado inesperado.

Para solucionar el probema pude hacer dos cosa:

1. Convertir a una cadena la fecha que devuelve el SYSDATE dentro de la función TO_DATE:

   ```
     TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'yyyy/mm/dd'))
   ```
2. Utilizar  sin conversión alguna

La primera alternativa es prácticamente redundante, por lo tanto, cambié mi insert colocando directamente el SYSDATE. Quedando de esta forma:

```
insert into pedido values (131,123,1001,SYSDATE, to_date('2021-10-04', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 25);
```

Comment: ¿Por qué?. Aunque estés respondiendo tu propia pregunta, por favor considera agregar una explicación, indica lo que estaba mal en el código original y cómo el nuevo código lo resuelve.

Answer (score 0):

Estuve ayer examinando el problema y aunque lo has resuelto veo alguna laguna en tu explicación. En relación a ese "resultado inesperado".

Si ejecutamos las siguientes sentencias podemos hacernos una idea de lo que está pasando

```
SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL;

SELECT TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'yyyy/mm/dd') FROM DUAL;
```

Resultado

```
SYSDATE 
---------
18-JUN-21


TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'YYYY/MM/DD')
-----------------------------
21-JUN-18
```

La primera consulta indica lo que nos está devolviendo SYSDATE, la fecha de hoy: 18-JUN-21. Al indicarle al método TO_DATE que su primer argumento está en formato YYYY/MM/DD toma los dos primeros dígitos como el AÑO y los dos últimos como el DÍA, es decir año 2018 y día 21. Este es el valor que pasas en tu INSERT como fechapedido.

Por ello esta condición del trigger

```
:new.fechapedido <= TO_DATE('2020/01/01', 'YYYY/MM/DD')
=
'2018/06/21' <= '2020/01/01'
=
TRUE
```

EXTRA
A la hora de depurar o examinar nuestro código, como apunte para saber cual es el valor de una condición booleana sin tener que ejecutar el trigger, podemos lanzar estas consultas sobre la tabla auxiliar DUAL.

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN (SYSDATE <= TO_DATE('2020/01/01', 'YYYY/MM/DD')) THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END) 
FROM DUAL;

SELECT (CASE WHEN (TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'YYYY/MM/DD') <= TO_DATE('2020/01/01', 'YYYY/MM/DD')) THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END) 
FROM DUAL;
```

Ejecutándolas obtendríamos

```
A   
-----
FALSE


B   
-----
TRUE
```